# Wordpress website is scrolling to the right

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I could use a second pair of eyes on a Wordpress theme I installed: http://ctrlaltdel.wpengine.com

I attempted to put a video background in the div "bg" and ran into some issues. In Chrome, it worked fine. Firefox/Safari/IE/etc.. not so much. So I removed the code.

However, the site is now scrolling to the right in all browsers.

I re-uploaded the original .css files for the site, but it's still moving it to the right.

The original demo, however, does not scroll horizontally: http://www.showthemes.com/tyler-demo/

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the footer.

```
<!-- 3-COL CONTENT -->
    <div id="tile_textcolumns" class="container widget ef_footer_text_columns">
```

Seems like the Navigation part is outside of the .container class, which causes it to overflow. Refer to the original demo for the correct structure